# Simultaneously write to multiple syslog facilities?

Tags: c, linux, logging, syslog

Is it possible to have one application simultaneously write to multiple syslog facilities?

I have an application, written in C/C++, that I would like to write some messages to local0 and other messages to local1.  I do not want the messages for local0 to appear in local1 or vice versa.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the man page for `syslog`, I see the example:

```
syslog(LOG_INFO|LOG_LOCAL2, "foobar error: %m");
```

Does

```
syslog(LOG_INFO|LOG_LOCAL0, "message for local0");
syslog(LOG_INFO|LOG_LOCAL1, "message for local1");
```

work?

Comment: I can't believe I didn't check the man pages before posting my question (palm meets forhead). After reviewing the man pages myself, I do believe that this will work for what I need to accomplish since the priority argument is formed by ORing the facility and the level values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a single call.  You'll have to make a call for each facility.